# How to update a mix of packages and ports on FreeBSD

Tags: package-management, freebsd, bsd-ports

I mostly use packages on FreeBSD, because most of them suit me just fine. Some don't suit me, however, like the `vim` package, which does not include a graphical `gvim`.

No problem. I can install the port instead, using `portmaster editors/vim` and selecting the `GTK2` option. This works fine.

However, when I run `pkg upgrade` after a while, I am presented with the following:

```
        Reinstalling vim-7.4.110_3 (options changed)
```

What gives? I didn't change any options, and there is no new version (not in ports, either). Is it comparing my installed port to the remote version without `GTK2`?

Of course I can let `pkg upgrade` do its work and install the port again afterward, but this is stupid. What is the recommended way to update a mix of packages and ports?

Comment: Is using `pkg lock` the recommended solution? It works, but I would hope something as simple as this could be handled automatically.

Comment: Yes, `pkg lock` is the solution designed for that: from the man page: “pkg lock is used to lock packages against reinstallation, modification or deletion.”.

Comment: this post is quit old. But I like to told that I have until now the same problem. I had asking the FreeBSD Forum ["Using packages and ports at the same time?"](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/51531/) And one member give me the advice to use a script for installation updates, like he has done. You can find it there in his answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to remember that `pkg` and ports register installed software in the same place (an SQLite database in `/var/db/pkg`). Neither system records any additional information that a particular piece of software was installed as a pre-compiled package, or as a port. Thus, once a piece of software is installed by either approach, the tools have no way of knowing *how* it was installed.

When you selected GTK2 support for the `editors/vim` port, that was registered in the package database. When you later ran `pkg upgrade`, `pkg` looked at the package data for `vim`, and found that GTK2 support had been enabled in the installed version, whereas it is not enabled in the pre-compiled package. `pkg upgrade` is doing exactly what it should - finding any installed packages that are different from the available pre-compiled packages, and attempting to upgrade them. Those differences can be in version number, dependency graph, compile-time options, etc.

The proper way to prevent `pkg` from considering a port or package (once installed, there is no difference, as far as the tools are concerned) that you want to protect is to use the `pkg lock` command.

Alternatively, if you find yourself changing options on a number of ports, you might consider installing `poudriere` and maintaining your own package repository. It takes a bit of setting up, and works best if your build host has a ZFS storage pool, although it will work if you don't have ZFS; it is a very flexible and convenient way to manage custom software builds.